# How to install Android SDK on CircleCI OSX

Tags: circleci

Android SDK is not installed by default on OSX plans. Is there a way to enable it or how to properly install it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding me. I figured it out! I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

```
machine:
  environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: "/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
    ANDROID_SDK_HOME: "/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
    ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: "/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
dependencies:
  override:
    - brew tap caskroom/cask
    - brew tap caskroom/versions
    - brew cask install android-sdk
```

Bonus tip: run `./gradlew --dry-run assembleRelease` as dependency override as well to get the Android / Java dependencies in the cache.

Comment: Could you please post a link to the full `.yml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `circle.yml` (or some variation to suit your needs). It uses `brew` to install the `android-sdk`. Then you download the Android packages you need (just as you would on a linux image in Circle). Finally, prepend your gradle calls with an environment variable for `ANDROID_HOME`.

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - brew install android-sdk
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-25,build-tools-25.0.2platform-tools,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository"

test:
  override:
    # Android
    - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk clean testDebugUnitTest
    - mv ./app/build/test-results/debug $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
```

Comment: @tristanbbq did you give this a try?